# How to customize the keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

How can we add custom buttons in default keyboard that has interface like the picture below.

[image]

How can I do like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Customizing the keyboard is a hard part since apple did not provide much to work on that.I will suggest a hack that whenever needed to show a keyboard show a custom view with buttons by managing keyboard notifications.and programatically hiding the orginal one.I dont know this is acceptable in appstore .Have some check on that first too

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this tutorial http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Comment: I tried this demo but I want to add buttons right hand side not in the empty place. I also tried to add button right hand side with this demo but it just added new above the 9 button. I don't want this. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just create a viewController with .xib and get screenshot of the above picture. fix screen shot over UIImageView Then you need to put custom UIButtons and set there tag property same as buttons intend to like 1,2,3 Then create a method assigned to all UIButtons and using their tag property do operations.

if you want to enter some text into UITextField then you need to implement delegate method of UITextFiled textShouldBeginEditing return no. Do you get some Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can provide a `UIView` to replace the keyboard... I have never used this feature however.

Answer (score -1):

You can add simple buttons to the `UIKeyBoard` by making them custom .

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {


// create custom button
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(215, 163, 106, 53);
doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIWindow* tempWindow;

UIView* keyboard;

for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
{
    tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];

    for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES)
        {
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Or check out this link for a customized keyboard layout

[BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls)